# Magento 2 : parent construct

Tags: magento2

Using magento 2.4.3 EE
I have extended a class

```
namespace Vendor\module\Block\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option;

use Vendor\module\Model\Attribute\Source\Order;

class Checkbox extends \Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Checkbox 

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper,
        \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
        \Bss\ProductStockAlert\Helper\Data $helper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $jsonEncoder,
            $catalogData,
            $registry,
            $string,
            $mathRandom,
            $cartHelper,
            $taxData,
            $pricingHelper,
            $data
        );
    }
```

this class extends `\Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Checkbox`
it has no constructor defined.

not sure if i need to add parent construct in this vendor/module file or not ?

Comment: What if class is extended to another class that also have parent construct ?
Then the custom modules's class must have parent construct or not ?

Comment: i am not getting any error even if i have not added few args in parent construct. compared to the main class. Still do i need to add those args s main class ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your this file :

> \Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Checkbox

Extended from another file and that file have `constructor` then you need to pass those parameter from here.

Comment: Thanks & that file is Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option right ?
So the module's file must have the constructor args same as this Option class also in same order.

Comment: yes, if answer help accepted as solution and upvote as well, so that will help other in community.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What if class is extended to another class that also have parent construct ? Then the custom modules's class must have parent construct or not ?

Comment: i am not getting any error even if i have not added few args in parent construct.
compared to the main class.
Still do i need to add those args s main class ?

Answer (score 1):

If the parent class does not have **__construct()** method, then it is not necessary to add parent **__construct()** method in your class.

In that case, you only need to add **__construct()** method in your class if your class **needs to add any new dependency**.

If the parent class has **__construct()** method defined, and you are using **__construct()** method in your class, then you need to use **parent::__construct()** method with all dependencies defined in the parent class's __construct() method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
perfect answer.